# Strange behavior regarding inline-block elements and margins within a container

Tags: html, css

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Adrift/F2a9U/2/)

In my example, giving either of the children elements a bottom margin causes its sibling to be pushed down by whatever margin I specify; I hadn't anticipated seeing anything move since the container is larger than each div. Why is this the case?

**HTML**

```
<div class=container>

    <section></section>
    <aside></aside>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
background: whitesmoke;
height: 12em;
width: 12em;
}

.container section {
background: slategray;
display: inline-block;
height: 04em;
margin-bottom: 20px;
width: 04em;
}

.container aside {
background: gold;
display: inline-block;
height: 04em;
width: 04em;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top` to your `section` element. As these elements are ìnline-block, they are not simply behaving as boxes anymore - they have flowing text properties. It is not really the `margin` that is pushing down the other element, it is the default `vertical-align` property they have.

- [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F2a9U/3/)
- [Other Demo that shows the effect with text](http://jsfiddle.net/F2a9U/4/) - the key is `vertical-align`

Comment: You shouldn't look at the second element as being pushed down, but rather staying aligned to the bottom of the whole line of inline blocks, which is now as high as the tallest element (in your case the section's height + the margin).

Comment: @MartinTurjak Sounds to be a better explanation than mine. I guess.

Comment: @bažmegakapa Thanks! Well it is really just jour vertical-align explanation, but turned around a tiny bit =) You still deserved my +1 ;-)