# Fluid layout divs with same height and table-cell style

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I need to show one big div with 3 divs inside it. The layout has to be fluid, i.e. the height of the big div must adapt to the contents of the 3 divs inside it. Moreover, I want the 3 divs have the same height, and I managed to do that with `display:table` property for the container div and `display:table-cell` property for the 3 inner divs. Nevertheless, there is a big problem: as soon as I put a div with a `margin-top:` inside the first of the three divs, it shifts downwards the content of the other two divs. 
I really cannot understand why, any help would be much appreciated.
Here is the html and the css code:

```
<div id="body">
    <div id="left-box">
        <div id="left-container">
            LEFT LEFT LEFT LEFT LEFT LEFT 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="central-box">
        <div id="central-container">
            CENTRAL CENTRAL CENTRAL CENTRAL CENTRAL  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right-box">
        <div id="right-container">
            RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#body {
    width:80.9%;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    height:auto;
    /*background-color:#0F3;*/
    display:table;

}

#left-box {
    height:100%;
    width:60%;
    background-color:red;

    display:table-cell;
    border-right:1px solid #000;


}



#left-container {

    background-color:#0CF;

    width:72%;
    margin-top:82px;
    margin-left:2%;


}


#central-box {

    background-color:#00F;
    display:table-cell;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
    width:20%

} 

#central-container {

    margin-top:0px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#FF0;
}

#right-box {

    background-color:#0C0;
    display:table-cell;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
    width:19%;


} 

#right-container {

    margin-top:0px;

    background-color:#FF0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `vertical-align` on the divs, for example something like this:

```
div {vertical-align:top;}
```

it is a similar phenomenon as with inline-block elements we discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492308/strange-behavior-regarding-inline-block-elements-and-margins-within-a-container)

here I put your code + vertical-align on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HjvL2/)